# Qr code scan from gallery but just scanned qr with black and white color

Tags: java, android, android-studio, qr-code, zxing

I have project, I make scan Qr code from gallery image. it works fine. But my problem is my app scanned only qr with black and white color. when I trying to add others qr image with blue and white, it can't read.

This is my code

```
//call the onactivity result method
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //doing some uri parsing
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                InputStream imageStream = null;
                try {
                    //getting the image
                    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //decoding bitmap
                Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                Scan.setImageURI(selectedImage);// To display selected image in image view

                int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()];
                //copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
                bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());

                RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
                BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

                Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader(); // use this otherwise
                // ChecksumException
                try {
                    Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> decodeHints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
                    decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
                    decodeHints.put(DecodeHintType.PURE_BARCODE, Boolean.TRUE);

                    final Result result = reader.decode(bitmap, decodeHints);
                    //*I have created a global string variable by the name of barcode to easily manipulate data across the application*//
                    barcode =  result.getText().toString();

                    //do something with the results for demo i created a popup dialog
                    if(barcode!=null){
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
                        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                        builder.setMessage("" + barcode);
                        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                        alert1.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent i = new Intent (getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });

                        alert1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                        alert1.show();}
                    else
                    {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
                        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                        builder.setMessage("Nothing found try a different image or try again");
                        AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
                        alert1.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent i = new Intent (getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });

                        alert1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

                        alert1.show();

                    }
                    //the end of do something with the button statement.

                } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ChecksumException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something weird happen, i was probably tired to solve this issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FormatException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Barcode/QR format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something weird happen, i was probably tired to solve this issue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: @sanjeev not yet..